# Best way to store and search through large list of key, value

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm going to create a java class for android project that give number and return regional name based on phone code ( it's for Local use)

Our phone numbers length is between 8 and 10, regional code length is 4 or 5.

1. whats the best way to store regional codes? Is `HashMap<Integer, String>` suitable for this reason `<region code, region name>`? ( data for each city could be til 200 records)
2. whats the best way to search through this? As I said earlier regional code length could be 4 or 5, then we should search at the first time between 4 digit and then if there was no any result search 5 digits?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. You can use HashMap to store the data.
After storing the data by using the keySet() method of HashMap you will get the list of all keys as a sorted(ascending) set.

After that using the contains() method of Set, You will know the region code exists or not irrespective of 4 or 5 digits ( Else you can try first 4 digits if it returns false then you can try 5 digits).

By submitting that key(region code) to your Map you will get the region name easily.

Answer (score 1):

Using a hashmap is going to be your best bet. It has a run time of O(1), so when searching for a key, so you can do something like:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hm.put("yourKey", 12345);
...//repeat as needed
hm.get("yourKey");
```

And that will be the quickest way to get your value. If the value exists, it will return the mapped value, otherwise it will return `null` if there is no mapping. The length of the key is irrelevant.